# A gap has appeared at the top of my DIV after adding z-index to the DIV below

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have just started putting a site together. Along the top I have a header image that has a drop shadow at the bottom. I have an image that I would like to sit just under this so that you can see the drop shadow at the top of the image. I have placed this below the header DIV and have placed a z-index with -1 as the value. This sits it nicely behind the DIV and then I have added an absalute position with 220px from the top. However after adding the z-index value it have brought my header DIV down slightly and has left a gap at the top?

MY HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
<div class="mainhome">
    <div class="header"></div>
            <div class="mainimage"></div>

</div>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

MY CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background-image:url(images/header-background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

.mainhome {
    width: 855px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.header {
    height: 236px;
    background-image:url(images/header-background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    clear:left;
}

.mainimage {
    width: 855px;
    height: 423px;
    background-color:#0C9;
    position:absolute;
    top:220px;
    clear:left;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set body margin 0

```
body {
    background-image:url(images/header-background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/LwWhv/)**